# Can "with regard to" and "in regard to" be used interchangeably?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice, writing

Can you please tell me if I can use "in regard to" and "with regard to" to mean the same thing in this sentence?

> Her instincts *with regard to* tricky situations are usually correct.

Comment: The best way to say "thanks!" is to up-vote answers you find useful ([comments just to say "thanks" are discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101124/official-reference-for-dont-leave-thank-you-comments)). Not only does that give a little reputation to the person that wrote the answer, it makes sure that good content "floats to the top". See the [Why is voting important?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) topic in the help center for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that in everyday English both can have the same meaning.

**[Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-with-regard-to)** says the following:

> You can use **with regard** or **in regard** to indicate that the
>   subject is being talked about.